# Cannot change the size of a popover

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I've been trying to create my own code, as well as copy and paste examples, but my popover seems to fill the entire screen. Generally my code looks like below, but like I said, I've tried at least two other examples (some with CGSizeMake(), sourceRect, sourceView), and the results are always the same.

```
Class TableView: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    let popover = UIViewController()

    func someButton() {
        popover.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        popover.preferredContentSize = CGSize(1, 1)
        let menu = popover.popoverPresentationController
        menu!.delegate = self
        menu!.barButtonItem = someOtherCorrectButton
        self.presentViewController(popover, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
     popover.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

     var popupHeight:CGFloat = 542
     let popupWidth = 400 as CGFloat
     popover.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400,popupHeight)
     let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!

    let screenSize: CGRect = window.bounds

    var XCordinate = (screenSize.width - popupWidth) / 2
    var YCordinate = (screenSize.height / 2) + 20

    let menu = popover.popoverPresentationController
    menu!.delegate = self
    menu!.sourceView = window            
    menu!.sourceRect = CGRect( x: XCordinate, y: YCordinate, width: 1, height: 1)
    self.presentViewController(popover, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

May be it works for you.

Comment: The size of the popup is the bounds of the entire screen. It's completely black. This works for you?

Comment: Yes but my popover controller is like let popover = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardID") as! YourViewController and my popover is display in center of my screen.

Comment: Yeah I already tried it with instantiating an already made ViewController on Main.storyboard. It still fills the entire screen.

Comment: Which device you are using? and have you tried change with popupHeight and popupWidth?

Comment: I tried it on iPhone 6s. I did try multiple heights and widths. There must be some setting that I must do before all of this, since all sample codes give me the same result. I have given up for now, and I will probably only be able to fix it by showing my laptop to someone who knows what they're doing. Thanks for your help though.